# Thermostat relocation

Tags: thermostat

My thermostat is close to the front door. My furnace kicks in every 10 minutes, even when I keep it at 65 F. I was told something exists that would work in place of the thermostat and read the temperature where it’s placed. For example I place this device in the center of the room away from the door. This way the furnace hopefully doesn’t turn on as often as it wouldn’t be reading the temperature near the front door, rather further away. My place is very old and I don’t want to move the thermostat and open a potential can of worms. What is this device called? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Very old place usually means bad sealing(drafts) and poor insulation.  Improving one or both will help on heating costs.  Sealing the front door better should help more than moving/adding to the thermostat.  Modern furnaces usually do come on more often to keep house temperature within a couple of degrees.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a clue what your house looks like, and where your HVAC equipment is located in relation to the thermostat.  Personally, IMO the best solution is to simply run some new thermostat cable to a more central location.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a thermostat remote sensor.

You will also need a thermostat that can receive the signal from a remote sensor.  When programed properly, the HVAC unit will react to only the signal from the sensor.

[Honeywell makes this model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012P7QBK8) the sensor can be purchased separately.

Comment: Not that you asked but a small in-wall electric heater near the front door will also help. The sensor helps by measuring temperature where it doesn't fluctuate so much. The extra heater helps to reduce the amount of fluctuation, where it's most needed.